# Missing manage.py while trying to install Graphite (with Django)

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-16.04, graphite

I am trying to install Graphite on Ubuntu following the instructions given here:

https://gist.github.com/albertohm/5697429

When I install the components, especially Django, I do not get any errors. However when I run these two commands

```
cd /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite
sudo python manage.py syncdb
```

I get an error saying that

> manage.py could not be found

I've tried many different ways of setting up Graphite but none worked :-( 
Can someone please help me as to why `manage.py` does not exist in the graphite web folder?

Comment: `/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite` is folder as per the docs, is it same path in your box? check `pwd` of the directory you did all installs!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are not in a directory where `manage.py` exists.

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

this command works only when you are in the where `manage.py` exists.

So use `cd` command  to go to that directory and then run the above command

Comment: Where will be that file? I am facing this same above issue after installation in MacOs

Comment: generally this file is in base directory of your project...or you can follow this link to find the file https://superuser.com/questions/226566/how-do-i-find-a-file-by-filename-in-mac-osx-terminal

Answer (score 0):

On debian, try
    `django-admin migrate`